# java.util.regex matching anything before expression

Tags: java, regex

I trying to tokenize following snippets by types of numbers:

```
"(0-22) 222-33-44, 222-555-666, tel./.fax (111-222-333) 22-33-44 UK, TEL/faks: 000-333-444, fax: 333-444-555, tel: 555-666-888"
```

and

```
"tel: 555-666-888, tel./fax (111-222-333) 22-33-44 UK"
```

and

```
"fax (111-222-333) 22-33-44 UK, TEL/faks: 000-333-444, fax: 333-444-555"
```

and so on.

The conception is that this can be any combination of  like "tel/faks" and "tel/fax numbers" after it or just a "tel/fax number" at the beginning of the string.

I make this:

```
"(?:.(?!((tel|fax|faks)[ /:.]+)+))++"
```

on example 1, but after find() it returns: (chars '_' were added by me)

  _(0-22) 222-33-44, 222-555-666,_
  _TEL./_
  _FAX (111-222-333) 22-33-44 UK,_
  _TEL_
  _FAKS: 000-333-444,_
  _FAX: 333-444-555_

it seems that I loosing one char in every group and combined types like "TEL/faks" are splited. I need also to grab  (if this exist, if not then default number is tel) for future processing.

How can I get rid of this?

ps. I use: case-insensitive

Comment: I'm trying to understand what the output you'd like looks like, an example would help.

Comment: @Lauri Lehtinen, thx for interest.

 I want to get strings like this I have written ("find()" - example) but not splited for example:
"_TEL/FAKS: 000-333-444,_"
rather than
"_TEL_
_FAKS: 000-333-444,_"

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just do "(0-22) .. rest of your string".split(","); ?

Comment: Example string is only one posibility of how input data may look. It may be as well: 
"tel (111-222-333) 22-33-44 UK, TEL/faks: 000-333-444" or "tel (111-222-333) 22-33-44 UK" or just "223-33-44".

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression means (roughly):

```
(?:                                 Match a group consisting of:
   .                                  any character
   (?!                                that is not followed by
      ((tel|fax|faks)[ /:.]+)+))      "tel" or "fax" or "fakx", followed by at least one
                                              punctuation character from [ /:.]
                                +   (multiple times)
```

That's why you get a missing character before "Tel", "Fax" etc - because your regular expression says never to match the character before "Tel", "Fax" etc.

That's also why "Tel./.faks:" gets split - because the last "." comes before "fax", so it doesn't get matched.

I would suggest constructing two regular expressions that match:

```
A - a telephone number (parens, digits, commas, spaces), with at least one digit
B - a telephone/fax designation ("fax", "faks", "tel", punctuation)
```

Then search for strings matching

```
B*A+
```

Comment: thx for reply. This is clear now. But I wonder how to solve this with single regexp.

Comment: Read carefully - I've given an explanation of how to solve it with one regexp in my answer :) The single regexp is "B*A+", but you'll have to figure out what A & B are (as it will depend on exactly what results you want).